# Add StoryBoard to the existing UINavigation with Tab bar project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an UI Navigation project with tab bar, each tab bar is contain XIB and ViewController, the project is loaded each ViewController from the App delegate by this method :

```
MyFourthView *fourthViewController;
 fourthViewController = [[MyFourthView alloc] initWithTabBar];
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                             initWithRootViewController:fourthViewController];
[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
```

Now I am trying to add storyboard to my project, and load it from the app delegate programmatically to be a fifth tab bar view, but I don't know how I can do that? because there is no XiB in the storyBoard so the above method isn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

If the fifth navigation controller you want to add to your tab bar is the root/initial viewcontroller in your storyboard you can instantiate it like this:

```
UINavigationController *fifthNavigationController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourstoryboardname" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

If its not, give it a storyboard id and instantiate it like this:

```
UINavigationController *fifthNavigationController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourstoryboardname" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardIdOfYourNavController"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try your code and check , the storyboard have master Table View Controller , so I couldn't convert it to xib .

Comment: why dont you move all your xibs to the storyboard instead?

Answer (score 0):

Apple documents switching to using Storyboards here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link , it's good but it's difficult to convert all my other views to storyboard , I just need to convert one storyboard to xib or load the storyboard from my app delegate.

Comment: In that case you can just instantiate the initial view controller like this: [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryBoard" bundle:NULL] instantiateInitialViewController];